# The argument type 'Null Function(Reaction, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Reaction, int, bool)'

Tags: flutter

Hello I am having the below error in my code. I really really appreciate any help! This is the error output

Error: The argument type 'Null Function(Reaction, int)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'dynamic Function(Reaction, int, bool)'.

- 'Reaction' is from 'package:flutter_reaction_button/src/reaction.dart' ('../../../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_reaction_button-1.0.7+3/lib/src/reaction.dart').
  onReactionChanged: (reaction, isChecked) {
  and

Error: A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'bool'.
if (isChecked) {
^

```
                                             ^




return FlutterReactionButtonCheck(
                          onReactionChanged: (reaction, isChecked) {
                            setState(() {
                              post.myReaction = Reaction(
                                  id: reaction.id,
                                  icon: reaction.icon,
                                  previewIcon: reaction.previewIcon);
                            });
                            if (isChecked) {
                              bool isNewReaction = false;
                              SocialReactionModel postReaction =
                                  _reactionsList.firstWhere(
                                      (element) =>
                                          element.postID == post.id,
                                      orElse: () {
                                isNewReaction = true;
                                String reactionString =
                                    getReactionString(reaction.id);
                                SocialReactionModel newReaction =
                                    SocialReactionModel(
                                        postID: post.id,
                                        createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
                                        reactionAuthorID:
                                            MyAppState.currentUser.userID,
                                        reaction: reactionString);
                                _reactionsList.add(newReaction);
                                return newReaction;
                              });
                              if (isNewReaction) {
                                setState(() {
                                  post.reactionsCount++;
                                });
                                fireStoreUtils.postReaction(
                                    postReaction, post);
                              } else {
                                postReaction.reaction =
                                    getReactionString(reaction.id);
                                postReaction.createdAt = Timestamp.now();
                                fireStoreUtils.updateReaction(
                                    postReaction, post);
                              }
                            } else {
                              _reactionsList.removeWhere(
                                  (element) => element.postID == post.id);
                              setState(() {
                                post.reactionsCount--;
                              });
                              fireStoreUtils.removeReaction(post);
                            }
                          },
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is an old version, try to use the latest version:

```
flutter_reaction_button: ^2.0.0
```